# Getting rtmp streams in GStreamer, creating a mosaic and sending the resulting rtmp

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp

I run the following code

```
     gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    videomixer name=mix \
            sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
            sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
            sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
            sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=100 \
            sink_4::xpos=200 sink_4::ypos=100 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147924'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_1 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147925'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_2 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147926'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_3 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147927'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_4 \
        mix. ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux streamable=true ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/test'
```

Thank you. We solved the problem with the mosaic. This is the working version.

Comment: error when I add the last line

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1) Main issue is "videomixer" has only one src pad. You are connecting it to two pads.
 -

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \

    videomixer name=mix \
            sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
            sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
            sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
            sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=100 \
            sink_4::xpos=200 sink_4::ypos=100 \
        ! xvimagesink
```

By doing this, you are connecting videomixer src_pad to sink pad of sixvimagesink

Again at the end, you are trying to connect videomixer src_ to rtmpsink using queue and other elements.

So you have to remove one of the connections.

If you don't want to connect to xvimagesink, just remove "! xvimagesink"

If you dont want to connect to rtmpsink, remove the "mix ! queue ! videoconvert ..." part.

2) If you want to retain connection to queue, there is the following issue.
You are connecting mix.sink_4 to mix.src.

```
... ! mix.sink_4 \
        ! mix. ! queue ! videoconvert ! ...
```

Remove the first "!" and "." in the last line.

```
... ! mix.sink_4 \
         mix ! queue ! videoconvert ! ...
```

Then it should not give syntax error.

**EDIT 1**

I think again you have made a mistake. You are connecting src of mix to mix.sink_0. I have corrected it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    videomixer name=mix \
            sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
            sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
            sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
            sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=100 \
            sink_4::xpos=200 sink_4::ypos=100 \
      \    /* You should not add "! .mix.sink_0" here. */
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147924'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_1 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147925'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_2 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147926'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_3 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147927'\
        ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_4 \
        mix ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux streamable=true ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/test'
```

Let me give some information about "name=" usage here.
You can name an element in gstreamer pipeline and use it to construct pipeline. It is mostly useful in complex pipelines. let me show its usage with a simple pipeline.

Assume the following is the required pipeline:

```
 srcelem ! elem1 ! elem2 ! elem3 ! sinkelem
```

It can be written as below.

```
elem2 name=named_elem \    /* Naming elem2 */
named_elem ! elem3 ! sinkelem \     /* Connecting elem2 to downstream pipeline part. Note that there is no "!" before "named_elem" */
srcelem ! elem1 ! named_elem /* Connecting elem2 to upstream pipeline part. Note that there is no "!" after "named_elem" */
```

If you read it carefully, it constructs the same pipeline which is mentioned earlier.

Comment: The syntax error is missing.
Another error message appears. Tell me please, what could be the problem?
`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link mix to queue0`
Examples of mosaic with rtmp on the network, I did not find.

Comment: @user2306100 There are more issues. Edited my answer.

Comment: without "." writes
`WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "mix"`

Comment: I edited the code in the question. New error. `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "mix"` Where can there be a error?

Comment: Thank you. Worked with "."
`! mix.sink_4 \
        mix. ! queue ! videoconvert`
 I thought I was mixing sound with streams.
Can you please tell me how to make a sound from rtmp in mosaic?

Comment: If an answer is worked, you accept the answer and close the question. DO NOT EDIT THE QUESTION as it will be useful for others facing similar issue. If you have more question, open a new one. I would say you re-edit the question and put the problematic pipeline which you had posted earlier.

Comment: created a new question "Add sound to the GStreamer mosaic"
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534611/add-sound-to-the-gstreamer-mosaic)