# Add sound to the GStreamer mosaic

Tags: audio, gstreamer, mixed, mosaic

This is the mosaic code GStreamer 2x2

```
     gst-launch-1.0 -e \
    videomixer name=mix \
            sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
            sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
            sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
            sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=100 \
            sink_4::xpos=200 sink_4::ypos=100 \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147924'\
        ! decodebin name=dec1 ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_1 \
        decodebin1. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audiomixer name=amix \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147925'\
        ! decodebin name=dec2 ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_2 \
        decodebin2. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147926'\
        ! decodebin name=dec3 ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_3 \
        decodebin3. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
    rtmpsrc location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/209147927'\
        ! decodebin name=dec4 ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
        ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=100 \
        ! mix.sink_4 \
        decodebin4. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
        mix. ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux name=mux streamable=true ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://streaming.example.com:1935/test'
        dec1. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audiomixer name=amix \
        dec2. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
        dec3. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
        dec4. ! queue ! audioconvert ! amix. \
        amix. ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! voaacenc bitrate=96000 ! audio/mpeg ! aacparse ! audio/mpeg, mpegversion=4 ! mux.
```

Thank you for your farewell. 
Working code.

Comment: You have not added logic for audio. May be you need to have a look on audiomixer element. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-audiomixer.html

Comment: Added audio logic to the example. Help to connect amix to the mix

Comment: You still have not read my answer to your previous question I guess. Mixer connection is again incorrect. amix is not connected to downstream (any sink).